# Bootstrap Nav Tabs Becomes Inactive on ReRender

Tags: bootstrap, commandlink, styleclass, nav-tab

I have a Bootstrap Nav Tabs (2 tabs) with some content in both tabs. The first tab has PageblockTable with StandardSetController Pagination.

[image]

When I click on Next button. The next set is rendered correctly. Everything is fine except **both the tabs Home and Menu1 becomes inactive**. The Home Tab should remain in Active.  How to set that?

[image]

```
<apex:pageBlock id="pbId">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Some content AND a PageblockTable with Standard Set Controller Pagination</p>  
      <apex:commandLink reRender="pbId" value="Next" action="{!next}"/>       
    </div>

    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
    </div>    
  </div>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

How to set the class as active on clicking the commandlink.  The commandlink should also execute {!next} method.

For reference, the next method is just this.

```
    public void next(){
        this.setcon.next();
        setApplication();
    }
```

Comment: I used standardSetController and tried to replicate what you are trying do, but on click of next button its working fine for me. Unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What's the rerender in your next command button?

Comment: i copied your code and placed a pageblocktable inside home section, rerendering the page block.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the bootstrap tab function again in onComplete function

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!next}" oncomplete="enableTab()">Next</apex:commandButton>

<script>
    var enableTab = function(){
        $('.nav-tabs').tab()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That didn't help :(

Comment: did u replace '.nav-tabs' with the element id/class that you need?

Comment: Isnt nav-tabs the one that should be enabled!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with something else.

The problem is to do with reRendering the HTML and not the JS at the same time. For instance, I like to use a JS based component called `PageBlockTableEnhancerADV`. I had something that looked a bit like this:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="adminpanel" rendered="{!isAdmin}">
  <apex:pageBlock title="Admin Panel">
    <c:PageBlockTableEnhancerADV targetPbTableIds="mycallstoday" pageSizeOptions="10,20,50,100,200" defaultPageSize="10" enableExport="false" />
    <apex:form>
      <apex:pageBlockTable id="mycallstoday" value="{!contacts}" var="c">
        <apex:column value="{!c.c.Name}" />
        <apex:column value="{!c.c.Phone}" />
        <apex:column value="{!c.c.Email}" />
        <apex:column value="{!c.c.MobilePhone}" />
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!doSomething}" value="Submit" reRender="mycallstoday" />
    </apex:form>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</c:outputPanel>
```

Notice I'm ReRendering the `pageBlockTable` here and not the `outputPanel`. This broke the JS used by the component.

When I rerendered the `outputPanel` instead, this worked and the JS initialised properly.

Basically the problem is all to do with re initialising the JS. You could do it be reRendering the component like in my case (or even reRendering something with Bootstrap's JS in it), but a cleaner approach would be just to reinitialise the specific function you're using when you reRender.

Comment: Thanks but I dont think its a rerender problem.  In my case, what do you think should be rerendered?

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy I would start with the actual jQuery link itself. Then try narrowing it down to the specific function.